# Is there a way to kill line breaks in git pretty-format strings

Tags: git

In git's pretty-format strings options such as `%b` may resolve to text containing line breaks. Is there an easy way to construct a format string eliminating these line breaks guaranteeing a single output line per commit?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible with the formatting itself. You might have to pipe to some other program.